# Copy a file X times renaming it with all alphabet letter

Tags: linux, bash

I have a database sqlite file called "a.db".

I need to copy it 25 times (once for each letter of the alphabet) to have: b.db, c.db, d.db... ... ... z.db.

How can I do this in the Bash shell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A for loop and brace expansion.

```
for pref in {b..z}
do
  cp a.db "$pref.db"
done
```

Comment: mmm .. it not work! I've simply copied and paste your code and run as bash shell... but it create a file: {a..z}.db

Comment: I solved using : for pref in q w e r t y u i o p a s d f g h j k l z x c v b n

Comment: Then you're not running bash, or you're running an ancient version.